# PHP verificar caracteres especificos

Tags: php

Eu criei uma formula que permite criar codigos assim

```
12345-6789-101112
```

O que eu quero agora é, quando for validar o formulario quero que vertifique se o codigo esta correcto por exemplo.

```
Se contem 5(00000) em cada 3(00000-00000-00000).
```

Existe alguma forma de o fazer?

Comment: Sim, conhece expressão regular? Aliás, o exemplo dado seria inválido, já que só possui 4 dígitos no segundo grupo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira é utilizar uma expressão regular para validar o formato especifico. `[a-z0-9]` siginica que apenas letras (a-z) e números (0-9) vão entrar na captura.

```
$str = '12345-67819-10111';
$regex = '/^[a-z0-9]{5}-[a-z0-9]{5}-[a-z0-9]{5}$/i';

$valido = preg_match($regex, $str);
```

Comment: Uma dúvida.. ele não aceita letras apenas numeros.. e eu queria tudo.. Letras e Numeros..

Comment: @user106225 na pergutna original não tinha e essa informação. É fácil corrigir.

Comment: Eu sei e peço desculpa por não ter expressado melhor, poderia ajudar-me então?

Comment: @user106225 editei a respostas. Você também pode fazer, com `explode()`, `str_len()` e um foreach é outra maneira :)

Comment: obrigado!!!!!!!